# Requirejs jsonp and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, json, requirejs

I am testing this JSON feed https://www.unisport.dk/api/sample/ using requirejs jsonp like this

```
require(['https://www.unisport.dk/api/sample/?callback=define'],
  function ( data ) {
    console.log( typeof data );
  }
);
```

as it is described here http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsonp. I have used https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to verify the feed. But this code snippet throws the following exception

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

My HTML looks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <script src="scripts/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="scripts/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.20/require.min.js" data-main="scripts/main"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery is not being used anywhere, there is no other code than whats been posted above.

Comment: The pointed resource is not `JSONP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONP is something that the remote server has to explicitly support, and it looks like the server you're pointing to doesn't.

It's returning plain JSON which, when evaluated as a script, will throw the error you're getting.